# How to sample multiple columns in the 2D matrix by using awk with for loop?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, awk, multiple-columns

I would like to sample multiple columns in the 2D matrix by using 'awk'.

For instance,

```
awk -F " " '{print $900, $925, $950, $975 $1000}' [filename].txt > test.txt
```

I just wrote five columns in the above command for example. In fact the number of columns would be over 40. The column number has a increment, 25, from starting number, $900.

Writing all $(column number) would be painful.

How could I make the command simpler by using for loop?
Or Any other suggestion?

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: Can you use [some of this](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/266120-awk-extract-value-column-using-variable.html) ? (not testet)

Comment: @MyICQ I just tried the last comment in the above site. I used the same code, changing only input. But, it's not working. I'm a beginner of the bash. What are $bjulian and $ejulian?

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: do you know the column numbers upfront and just need a way to feed them to `awk`? or do you need a way to *randomly* pick X number of columns?

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, I know the upfront number and I  just need to insert the multiple numbers with rule in `awk`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> jot -s ' ' -w 'Col-%d' 2000 | 
>
> mawk '{ print '"$( jot -s ', ' -w '$%d' 40 900 - 25 )"'"" }'
> ```

```
 1  Col-900
    Col-925
    Col-950
    Col-975
    Col-1000
    Col-1025
    Col-1050
    Col-1075
    Col-1100
    Col-1125
    Col-1150
    Col-1175
    Col-1200
    Col-1225
    Col-1250
    Col-1275
    Col-1300
    Col-1325
    Col-1350
    Col-1375
    Col-1400
    Col-1425
    Col-1450
    Col-1475
    Col-1500
    Col-1525
    Col-1550
    Col-1575
    Col-1600
    Col-1625
    Col-1650
    Col-1675
    Col-1700
    Col-1725
    Col-1750
    Col-1775
    Col-1800
    Col-1825
    Col-1850
    Col-1875
```

The trick is to use `jot` (or `seq`, or something similar) to dynamically generate code with hard-coded column #s :

for the example above, this code is being generated on the fly :

```
mawk '{
    print $900,  $925,  $950,  $975, $1000, $1025, $1050, $1075,
         $1100, $1125, $1150, $1175, $1200, $1225, $1250, $1275,
         $1300, $1325, $1350, $1375, $1400, $1425, $1450, $1475,
         $1500, $1525, $1550, $1575, $1600, $1625, $1650, $1675,
         $1700, $1725, $1750, $1775, $1800, $1825, $1850, $1875, "" }'
```

Comment: Kpop Maifesto When I use only `mawk '{ print '"$( jot -s ', ' -w '$%d' 40 900 - 25 )"'"" }' [filname].txt` it's working very well in a way that I want.  jot is very useful!! I really appreciate that.

Comment: @ChangwanSun : so i was testing to see how far i could push that concept - i split a `466 MB` file byte by byte, then literally ask it to start printing out  `$487572261, $488354881, $489137501…` (that's field # 489-***million***) - `mawk2` managed to split it out to nearly half a billion fields, and print out 625 evenly spaced fields in just `7.773 secs`

Comment: Yes. I need to study `mawk` and `mawk2` more.  Your suggestion has upgraded my skill. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ChangwanSun : run this :::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::: `echo ' 1 < 3 0 ' | gawk -p- -be  "$( echo ' >= == <> != <= > < ' | awk 'NF && sub("[^ \t]+", (_++? "||" : "")(" ( \"&\"==$2 \\&\\& (+$1 "(/<>/ ? "!=" : "&")" +$3)!=$4 ) "))' RS='[^!-~]+' ORS= )"` ::::::::: say if you're trying to write a function that can take 2 nums and a comparison string & perform the requested comparison, and wanna check whether any outcomes came out incorrectly, instead of looping, this gets you the exact `regex` u need...

Comment: ….  even allowing the user to use `awk`-invalid comparison operators like `"<>"` for `not-equal-to`, and auto adjust the `regex`. The `"echo ' 1 < 3 0 '`  was a faulty outcome intentionally included so the regex will match it

Answer (score 1):

using @RARE Kpop Manifesto's idea...

`awk` probably an overkill here, if your delimiters are normalized to tab

```
$ cut -f"$(seq 900 25 1000 | paste -sd,)" file > file.sample
```

otherwise provide delimiter `-d' '`

Comment: you can combine the middle portion of `seq + paste` into `jot -s ',' - 900 1000 25` - there's a slight difference if one were to use `seq` trying to emulate the same effect : `seq -s ',' 900 25 1000` yields `900,925,950,975,1000,%` (no trailing `\n`), while `jot -s ',' - 900 1000 25` gives `900,925,950,975,1000`

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
A B C D E F
AA BB CC DD EE FF
AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF
```

and say I want to get odd columns starting at 1 that is 1, 3, 5 then

```
awk 'BEGIN{pitch=2}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=pitch){printf "%s%s",$i,(i+pitch>NF?"\n":" ")}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
A C E
AA CC EE
AAA CCC EEE
```

Explanation: I do use `for` loop with increment by `pitch` which is `2` in example, starting is from `1` and condition is `i` less equal number of fields (`NF`), in each turn of loop I use `printf` once, first element is simply value of `i`th column (`$i`), second is newline (`\n`) - if said element is last in given line or space for all other cases. I use number of current column (`i`), `pitch` and number of columns (`NF`) to calcute if this is last value to be included in current line and then so-called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse to select fitting character.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Ok. It's working for your example. But I need to have a better understanding. Why did you use %s%s?

Comment: @ChangwanSun when using `printf` you might use `%s` to denote where value or values will be inserted, if you want to know more read about [Printf in GNU Awk's User Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html)